# gnome-terminal. New tab opening

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am launching the gnome-terminal and I am working in a specific path, for example: `/home/user/programs/c`.

Now I am opening another tab. When I am opening the new tab it is also in the same path, i.e. the new tab's working directory will be `/home/user/programs/c`.

But what I want is when I am opening a new tab its working directory should be `/home/user`.

How can I achieve this?
Any help much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Same problem, I'd like the old behavior. No options in dconf. - From [user1585507](http://superuser.com/users/221897/user1585507)

Answer (score 2):

[Same as here](https://superuser.com/questions/596764/how-to-change-gnome-terminals-startup-directory)

The solution is to check "Run command as a login shell" in the preferences. It worked for me.

[Check the FAQ](https://live.gnome.org/Terminal/FAQ#How_can_I_make_new_terminals_start_in_the_working_directory_of_the_current_terminal.3F)

Comment: No, that's what you would do if you wanted each tab to continue in the same directory but it wasn't working. Op has the opposite problem, it's currently doing that and he wants it to start in the home directory each time.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the FAQ](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Terminal/FAQ?action=show&redirect=Terminal%2FFAQ#How_can_I_make_new_terminals_start_in_the_working_directory_of_the_current_terminal.3F):

> Since version 3.7, for new terminals to start in the working directory of the current terminal, it is necessary for the shell running in the terminal to cooperate. For this, vte since version 0.34.5 installs a `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh` script that when sourced will set this up automatically. It supports both `bash(1)` and `zsh(1)`.

I took a look at `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh`, but I honestly don't know where in that script this is happening. Ignoring that, you can achieve your desired outcome by modifying the `gnome-terminal` preferences. Not a very elegant solution, but it works for me using `zsh` and Debian 10.

- "Profile" > "Command"
- Check "Run a custom command instead of my shell"
- Use the binary for your shell in the "Custom command" text box

[Screenshot of Gnome Terminal preferences in Debian 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD4Vh.png)

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any way to override this behaviour from withing gnome-terminal itself.  The easiest workaround that I have found is to add an explicit `cd` to your `~/.bashrc` file.

```
echo 'cd $HOME' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then when you open a new tab, it will change the current directory back to your home directory.

Comment: Nice fix. I hope they will integrate it in the next version of Gnome Terminal. Konsole is my primary terminal emulator, though. :-)

Comment: Alan, actually it's a feature that GNOME terminal starts new tabs in the current directory.

Comment: @PaoloBonzini, indeed I agree, it's a feature.  Unfortunately the behaviour seems to have changed with Gnome 3.8.  How do I get back the old behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of gnome-terminal that everyone seems to like but me and thillai-selvan. There is a lot of documentation on how to fix it when it's not working right (that is, when a new tab is opening in the same directory as the previous tab). However, there is little information on how to disable the feature. It can't be disabled in the gnome-terminal UI or any config files as far as I can tell. So you need to break it or circumvent it.

For my use case, `echo 'cd $HOME' >> ~/.bashrc` is not a good solution, because in some applications I would like them to be able to open in a different directory, mainly the embedded terminal in vscode, and that line in bashrc will prevent it.

The feature is implemented by providing a PROMPT_COMMAND that records the current directory every time a prompt is generated. Current versions of gnome implement this by installing a `vte` script into `/etc/profile.d`. You should be able to remove that file (back it up so you can restore it later if you want) and disable this feature.