# How to change gnome-terminals startup directory?

Tags: linux, gnome-terminal

It seems like gnome-terminal has changed its startup behavior and now new shells opened via CTRL-SHIFT-N have ~ set as their working directory. Before this change the new shell was opened in the current directoy.

How do I revert this change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the official gnome-terminal [FAQ](https://live.gnome.org/Terminal/FAQ#How_can_I_make_new_terminals_start_in_the_working_directory_of_the_current_terminal.3F)
See also [this bugreport](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=697475).

Comment: Oh ... should have done this first ...

Answer (score 3):

If you use Debian and don't want to wait for the different maintainers to finally decide where "the best position for the script" is, you can do the following:

Edit `~/.bashrc`, search for the following lines (might look slightly different):

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

and add to the else branch:

```
  # XXX hack to fix ctrl + shift + N
  . /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
```

Resulting in:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
  # XXX hack to fix ctrl + shift + N
  . /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bash and Z shell, add this to your shell's rc file (that is, `~/.bashrc` or `/.zshrc`):

```
source /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
```

(This solution is promoted from comments to other answers.)